# iPhone: Best way to store and retrieve a NSManagedObject connected to a UIControl

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject, uicontrol

I'm a beginner working on a Core Data app which has two Entities - "Control" and "Value" with a one-to-many relationship. (Control<-->>Value). Each "Control" represents a UIControl (UITextField, UIButton etc) which are added programmatically to a UIView. "Value" represents the control's value (text, title etc)

Since a view can have many text fields, how do I "connect" a certain text field to a specific "Value"? When I change the text in a text field I want to save it in the corresponding managed object (Value). Should I use tags and NSManagedObjectID?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of ways to approach this. One thought is to include a "tag" column in the entity and use that to correlate a unique value that gets put in the UI control's tag value.

I would also question whether "why" you're doing this, but I know that really wasn't the question.

Comment: Thanks! Why? I thought it was the only way to keep track of and update the db values in a certain text field using for example "textFieldShouldReturn"

Comment: I ended up using a "tag" column as suggested, using it as the UIControl tag and then putting the tag into a dictionary together with the mo's objectID. This solution seems to work but there are probably better ones. Thanks anyway for leading me into the right direction!